# Can more features decrease the performance

Tags: svm

I am running different algorithms (SVM, Random Forest, other tree-based decision algos).

I noticed that my performance went down (error went up) after adding new features.

```
performance(Feature_family_1 + Feature_family_2) < performance(Feature_family_1)
```

Is this possible, and how can I make sure I don't lose information? Should I use PCA?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of:

[Why does increasing the number of features reduce performance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41685/why-does-increasing-the-number-of-features-reduce-performance)

where I found this explanation very good:

> adding irrelevant predictors can worsen performance on new data -
>   increased variance of the prediction (over fitting). This is because
>   you end up fitting to noise and dilute the "true signal".

Also:

> In addition with the dimension you might have increasing possibility
>   of having correlated features which is not good for lots of learning
>   algorithms